# jQuery focus textbox and go to end, but ALSO set the position of the cursor so user can see it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here's what I'm working on:

http://jsfiddle.net/hn8EY/

```
$("input").mouseup(function(){
    this.selectionStart = this.value.length;
    this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
});
```

This is working fine for physically setting the position of the cursor, but I also want it to be where the viewpoint of the user jumps to that point, so that the current position of the cursor is actually shown.  I don't know if there is any solution to this.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: What I mean is, imagine you're somehow at the end of the text box.  The cursor would be there, but you would also see where you are in the text box.  With this code that I have, it does move the cursor position, but stays at the beginnign of the text box every time.  This is basically for text that goes outside the width of its element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the scrollLeft:

```
$("input").mouseup(function(){
    var valLength = this.value.length;
    this.setSelectionRange(valLength , valLength ); //or this.selectionStart = this.value.length; this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
    //or just use this.selectionStart = this.value.length;
    this.scrollLeft = this.scrollWidth;
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3vHc/)**