# Autofocus With Cursor On End Of Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to put autofocus on a html textbox such that the cursor points to the end of some text already present in the textbox. 
I know what the autofocus attribute does.  And I have also seen [put cursor at end of text input's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780756/put-cursor-at-end-of-text-inputs-value) which answers how to put cursor at the end, But the textbox is not autofocussed upon page reload. How can I do both - autofocus the textbox upon page reload and put cursor to end of text ?

```
Code : 

 <textarea id="txtArea" style="width:106%; height:100px" align="center" name="task1" onkeypress="onTestChange();" onfocus="this.value = this.value;" autofocus ><?php echo $_GET["task"];?></textarea>
```

I want to put Cursor after the text echoed. It is not the value of the textarea.

Also the textbox I referred to is Textarea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252449/jquery-focus-textbox-and-go-to-end-but-also-set-the-position-of-the-cursor-so-u

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fuhhxcrk/ Do you want some thing like this.

Comment: <input type="text" autofocus value="value text" onfocus="this.value = this.value;"/>
<input type="text" autofocus value="value text" onfocus="this.value = this.value;"/>

Comment: try to run above code

Comment: @kki3908050 Not Working Cursor still points at beginning only

Comment: please check this link out................
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tgzDL

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/511088/5468463

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please use this code and run in your browser

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    var input = $("#test");
    var len = input.val().length;
    input[0].focus();
    input[0].setSelectionRange(len, len);

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" autofocus value="value text" />
```

Answer (score 3):

try to run this simple code and see  u will notice that first text box will be focused and not the second

```
<input type="text" autofocus value="value text" onfocus="this.value = this.value;"/>
<input type="text" autofocus value="value text" onfocus="this.value = this.value;"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. Focus it, and set the value again.

```
<input type="text" value="this holds a value" id="element"/>

<script>
$(window).ready(function(){
   $("#element").focus(); 
   $("#element").val($("#element").val());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 var t =$("#txtID");    

 t.focus().val(t.val());

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [chris G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609476/30433) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609405/set-focus-after-last-character-in-text-box). Call function after you have set the focus to the textbox:

```
   function SetCaretAtEnd(elem) {
            var elemLen = elem.value.length;
            // For IE Only
            if (document.selection) {
                // Set focus
                elem.focus();
                // Use IE Ranges
                var oSel = document.selection.createRange();
                // Reset position to 0 & then set at end
                oSel.moveStart('character', -elemLen);
                oSel.moveStart('character', elemLen);
                oSel.moveEnd('character', 0);
                oSel.select();
            }
            else if (elem.selectionStart || elem.selectionStart == '0') {
                // Firefox/Chrome
                elem.selectionStart = elemLen;
                elem.selectionEnd = elemLen;
                elem.focus();
            } // if
        } // SetCaretAtEnd()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your link already auto focused on page load.

```
<input type="text" autofocus value="value text" onfocus="this.value = this.value;"/>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaGL5/35/)

Comment: Like what the poster said this only works on first load. He wants it to focus every request